# Execute sqlplus command in perl

Tags: oracle, perl, sqlplus

I am trying to check sql connection via sqlplus command in perl.
I have used the following code to do this.

```
print "Befores\n";
$rc=system("sqlplus system/system @sqlfile.sql");
print "After $rc\n";
sleep(10);
```

The returnes value in rc is 0 this time. But when I give wrong credentials like. The sqlfile.sql file contains the only sql command 'EXIT'.

```
$rc=system("sqlplus systemabc/system @sqlfile.sql");
```

This also ends with the return code 0. But, manually doing the Credentials are wrong.
Help me out in solving this...

Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: According to http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/system.html, $? may give you the information you're looking for.

Comment: Is `@sqlfile` an actual Perl array you are trying to interpolate, or is that a mistake you made? You should use `use strict; use warnings;` to catch errors like that. Also, `system ` does not return the output of the command, it returns the exit status. If you want output, use backticks or `qx()`.

Comment: @TLP: According to http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14357/ch3.htm#sthref798 the OP is using the correct syntax to have sqlplus execute the sql commands in the file sqlfile.sql.

Comment: @DavidHarris Well, in Perl he can't use an unescaped `@` in a double quoted string like that unless he wants to interpolate an array.

Comment: @ TLP: You are correct. The OP should have escaped the @ or used single quotes to prevent interpolation.

Comment: Don't do this, use DBI as per my answer below. Also look at the documentation for [system](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/system.html), you're using it wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes dear friens,,,
It's working fine now.

I just added '\' before @sqlfile.sql, i.e, I escaped the '@' symbol and I mentioned the database name after my password. Now I am getting the perfect output. :)

The change is as bellow:

```
$rc=system("sqlplus -L system/system@tstdb1 \@sqlfile.sql");
```

Here the format I used is: 
**sqlplus -L  Uname/Password@DBName \@SqlFileContainingMySQLQuries**

And -L Specifies not to reprompt for username or password if the initial connection does not succeed. For more info goto [About SQLPLUS](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14357/ch3.htm#sthref798)

I also tried without escaping the '@' symbol before sqlfile.sql, But the change also should apply for inverted comas, I used Single inverted comas instead of double inverted comas as bellow as mentioned by @René Nyffenegger :

```
$rc=system('sqlplus -L system/system@tstdb1 @sqlfile.sql');
```

Here the format I used is:
 **sqlplus Uname/Password@DBName @SqlFileContainingMySQLQuries**

This also works fine.

Answer (score -1):

Yeah... :) I too tried this, Thanks for the answer @user252025

I was doing:

```
$rc=system("sqlplus -L user/user \@sql_file.sql");
```

Da rtrn code was wrong for me
Now I ve changed to

```
$rc=system("sqlplus -L user/user@Mydb \@sql_file.sql");
```

Its working fine.. 
Thanks again...

Answer (score -2):

The problem is the line

```
$rc=system("sqlplus system/system @sqlfile.sql");
```

You have a string quoted with double quotes (`"..."`). Such strings try to epxand variables (starting with `@`, `$` and `%`). Since you have `@sqlfile` in the string, perl assumes this to be an array (which, of course it is not).

Remedy:

```
$rc=system('sqlplus system/system @sqlfile.sql');
```

Answer (score -3):

Why are you doing this? [DBI](http://search.cpan.org/~timb/DBI-1.631/DBI.pm) exists to provivide a sane and secure way of using databases and sensibly getting the output/return/errors from them.

Comment: Maybe, this script has been in use for long and nobody knows who the original developer is and it is unmaintainable etc. In such case I could imagine this a valid reason for trying what the OP wants.

Comment: @RenéNyffenegger From the description there is no suggestion that OP is not the original developer. Regardless, DBI provides a much cleaner way of interacting with databases.